# Creating CKAN dataset from external API and synchronize the datasets

Tags: ckan

I'm new to CKAN I would like to see if I can import data sets from external API and synchronize data based on API changes whats the best way to import and update from External API.

Appreciate your answers

Answer (score 0):

If your import will happen more than once, or it is from a source that has a supported API already, then it's strongly recommended to use ckanext-harvest. This provides a management interface and various help with matching up datasets previously harvested. It's extensible for new API types. See: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/

For one-off import of datasets into CKAN, for other APIs, you can simply create them directly using the CKAN API e.g. create_package. There are clients for many languages. See: https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/api/